# how to bind event to an element which was stopped propagation by javascript using mshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, mshtml, stoppropagation

I am using SHDocVm/mshtml to write ie's BHO with C#.

I want to get the object which was clicked control of binding an onclick event,

but the control was stopped propagation(e.stopPropagation) by javascript.

So i can not to get the object by the onclick event.

The Question is:
How can i get the object which was stopped propagation by javascript.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do not use onclick event, but onmouseup event can get the object.